# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined cordova 3.6

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode, pdf417

I am working on phonegap project. I need to send email from my phonegap application. I followed [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) tutorial. When I run the application , I am getting the above error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" . My cordova version is 3.6.3.

```
<script>
 function exc()
    {

        cordova.plugins.email.open({
            to:      'max@mustermann.de',
            cc:      'erika@mustermann.de',
            bcc:     ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
            subject: 'Greetings',
            body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
        });
    } 
</script>
```

can you tell me what might be wrong, where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Make sure you are trying to test from a device or simulator.  Native device plugins do not work in the web browser.

Comment: @NicRaboy yeah I tested with my phone only. Though I am getting this issue.

Comment: I think your plugin is not loaded. Please put your code in deviceready and try to run that code again. Did you install your email plugin using CLI?

Comment: @KRIZTE   document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        
      cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
           function (isAvailable) {
               // alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable;
           }
       );
     }, false);
     still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @KRIZTE I added plugin using CLI and I added  <feature name="EmailComposer">
        <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.EmailComposer" />
    </feature>

Comment: have you configured your plugin in cordova_plugins file and config.xml

Comment: @MohammedImranN I didn't configure cordova_plugins file on config.xml. I just configures EmailComposer plugin in plugins.xml

Comment: you have to do in cordova_plugin.js and config.xml

Comment: @chitti issue is solved? I faced the same issue now